# IS there a perl regex modifier to to literal matching always?

Tags: regex, perl, interpolation

I spent 2 hours today on forums , and reading Larry's Bible (Programming Perl) and I can't find a construct I'd expect to see.

I want to do a literal regex match, but I can't see a way to do it except the clumsy and sometimes ineffective \Q\E , which still interpolates vars.

For equality we have

```
$var eq "$test";
```

or

```
$var eq '$test'
```

, a simple and effective way to turn off interpolation (the only zinger is "'" itself of course..)

But what if I want to see if '$test' is contained in $var?  Is there a regex equivalent for this, like say a "q" switch:

```
$var =~/$test/ # interpolate

$var =~ /$test/q # don't interpolate anything, match literally
```

I thought maybe m/$test/ might work but no joy. Even \Q\E doesn't work.

In a related note, it's surprisingly difficult to find a list of all regex modifiers and what they do (like /g /i etc etc...). In Larry's Bible, there is a list of command line modifiers, but I couldn't find a list of regex modifiers. Or online.

Comment: hmmm, By far and large, it only makes sense to use `\Q\E` when you are interpolating, so saying `\Q\E` doesn't prevent interpolation doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

If you use single quotes with `m` ie `$var =~ m'$test'`, then $test is not interpolated, but you still need to use `\Q ... \E` to quote meta characters in the regex. You could use the quotemeta() function, which is what \Q ... \E uses under the hood. So

```
$quoted = quotemeta($test);
$var =~ $quoted;
```

Note that the section "Regexp Quote-Like Operators" in perlop lists all the modifiers.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to check whether `$var` contains `'$test'` literally is probably

```
if (index($var, '$test') >= 0)
```

To avoid variable interpolation in a regex match, use `'` as the delimiter:

```
if ($var =~ m'$test')
```

However, this will interpret `$` as a regex metacharacter (end-of-string anchor), so you still need `\$` to match a literal dollar sign.

This is documented in [Regexp Quote-Like Operators in `perldoc perlop`](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#m/PATTERN/msixpodualngc). For regex modifiers, see [Modifiers in `perldoc perlre`](https://perldoc.pl/perlre#Modifiers). (`perldoc` is the documentation viewer that comes with perl; the manuals are also available online e.g. at https://perldoc.pl/.)

If you want to match a piece of text completely literally and you can't use [`index`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/index) for some reason, your best bet is probably:

```
my $string = '$test';
if ($var =~ /\Q$string/)
```